# Как настроить чувствительность к регистру у названия базы данных mySQL?

Tags: mysql, windows

Задача, переношу базу данных локально на винду, восстанавливаю из дампа. Но нужно чтобы названия таблиц сохранились чувствительность к регистру. 
Т.е. названия таблиц начинаются с большой буквы.

в файл my.ini вставил строку lower_case_table_names=2

Но таблицы все равно получились с маленькой буквой.

Где ошибка? И какие могут быть рекомендации?

Comment: А тип таблиц InnoDB ? Ведь если они MyISAM то таблицы лежат на диске в виде файлов, а в винде имена файлов не чувствительны к регистру ... Ну и конечно имена таблиц при создании должны быть заключены в обратные апострофы

Comment: апострофы помогли